# How to test that an object is not a function in scala

Tags: function, scala, reflection, types

My problem is quite simple : I want to have an implicit conversion of value to function *if they are not already function*. I plan to use a type safe pattern by requesting the instantiation of an implicit parameter (if the valueis a function the implicit creation fails). 
However I do not see how to test that a value is not a function

I learned type safe pattern from user Beryllium in one of my previous question. See :
[Type safe method chaining that doesn't allow repeats of operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882998/type-safe-method-chaining-that-doesnt-allow-repeats-of-operations)

The implicit I've implemented is working, but too well. I want to transform not function expression to specific-application-default function automatically

```
 implicit def defaultExecutionUnitParameterNReturn(a: Any): Unit => MyDefaultReturn = 
{u : Unit => a }.andThen(_ => defaultReturn())
```

However my application would fail if the user implements "a" as a function

So my first idea was something like

```
 implicit def defaultExecutionUnitParameterNReturn[A](a: A)(implicit e : A =!= Function) Unit => MyDefaultReturn = 
{u : Unit => a }.andThen(_ => defaultReturn())
```

where implicit =!=[A,B] fails if A and B are the same type.
But "Function" does not exists

Comment: Coo, please paste your code. How do you try to convert object into function and how it fails?

Comment: and i'm interested in type safe pattern or do you mean type class?

Comment: Please don't use the word "object" as a synonym for "value," since in Scala `object` is a keyword for creating a special kind of value. Secondly, don't use "function" as a synonym for "method," since their quite distinct in Scala and only `FunctionN` are first-class values. When you ignore these distinctions, your question becomes ambiguous and hard to interpret.

Comment: @Randall Schulz : you absolutely right, i corrected to "object" into "value". "Function" was correctly used.

Comment: @AlexIv post edited with a link to the type safe pattern

Comment: @pawel.panasewicz post edited with a code example

Answer (score 2):

You need to place your implicit conversions in 2 traits

```
trait Implicits extends ImplicitsLow {
  implicit def convertFunction[T, R](f: T => R) = ???
}

trait ImplicitsLow {
  implicit def convert[T](t: T) = ???
}
```

Then you can observe that the function conversion is used in preference to the value one:

```
val result1: String = (i: Int) => i + 1
val result2: String = 1

// prints (function, value)   
println((result1, result2))
```

Comment: do implicits cascade? That's news to me!

Answer (score 0):

Investigate below code snipped. This is standard implicit convertion example. `toFunnction0` takes anything and converts it into `Function0[R]` or just simplified `() => R`.

```
implicit def toFunnction0[R](r: => R): Function0[R] = () => r

def iWantFunction0(f0: () => String) = {
  f0()
}

def testFun = {println("computing string in testFun..."); "ABC"} //every time when called block of code will run
val abcVal = "ABC" //this is computed only once

iWantFunction0(testFun)

//here abcVal is not a function, so implicit works. 
//toFunnction0 is in scope, so compiler will translate it into
//iWantFunction0(toFunnction0(abcVal))  
iWantFunction0(abcVal)
```