# Is there a way to provide custom compile error messages in Scala?

Tags: scala, annotations

Say I am building a library and I want to provide certain custom compile time error messages to users. Is there a way to provide this in Scala, perhaps using annotations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### @implicitNotFound

You could use `@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Custom message.")` to provide your custom error message in case if implicit parameter is not found. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17884093/406435) as example of usage.

#### Macros

You could also provide custom compilation error messages from macro implementation using method `Context#abort`.

```
scala> f"%s"
<console>:8: error: percent signs not directly following splicees must be escaped
              f"%s"
                ^
```

This messages is [provided](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/MacroImplementations.scala#L98) by function `macro_StringInterpolation_f`.

Example:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import reflect.macros.Context

def half(ie: Int): Int = macro halfImpl

def halfImpl(c: Context)(ie: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Int] = {
  import c.universe.{ Constant, Apply, Literal }

  val i = ie.tree match {
    case Literal(Constant(i: Int)) => i
    case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "call this method with literal argument only.")
  }

  if (i % 2 == 0) c.literal(i / 2)
  else c.abort(ie.tree.pos, "can't get half of odd number.")
}
```

Errors:

```
scala> half(2)
res0: Int = 1

scala> half(3)
<console>:1: error: can't get half of odd number.
              half(3)
                   ^

scala> val i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> half(i)
<console>:2: error: call this method with literal argument only.
              half(i)
                  ^
```