# Can Groovy Trait Return Implementing Type Suitable for Method Chaining

Tags: groovy, traits

Is it possible to incorporate trait methods along with methods on the implementing class using method chaining?  This requires that the trait return the specific type of the implementing class, and the "this" variable is not that type by default.

Something like:

```
def withFilter(String filter){
    this.filter = filter
    return (super.getClass())this
}
```

According to the top answer on the post below, it looks to be pretty easy to achieve with Scala Traits, but I don't understand the syntax exactly. It looks like it uses a closure which defines it's return type, but is the same possible in Groovy?

[Best practice to implement Scala trait which supports method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826392/best-practice-to-implement-scala-trait-which-supports-method-chaining)

Comment: So, it looks like "this" actually does have the type of the implementing class, however I was going off of intelliJ intellisense, which does not seem to recognize that, and when trying to chain another method after it gets underlined with "cannot resolve symbol".  However, it works. i will open a ticket with Intellij.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics approach.

Here is an example

```
trait MyTrait<T extends MyTrait<T>> {
    def filter

    T withFilter(String filter) {
        this.filter = filter
        return (T) this
    }
}

class MyClz implements MyTrait<MyClz> {
    def clzMethod() {}
}

def clz = new MyClz()
        .withFilter("hello")
        .withFilter("another")
        .clzMethod()
```

Comment: This is a very succinct, clear, and relevant answer.  I was able to take the proposed solution, apply to it my scenario, and it just worked.   Thank you SO much!  Followup question:  What is the benefit of making the first line specific:  ( <T extends MyTrait<T>> instead of just <T> )   I see that it works if I just make it <T>, but i'm sure there's a reason for what you did.

Comment: @JerryW. The only reason in this particular case is to prevent some type errors like `MyClz implements MyTrait<Integer>`